# ASP.NET FTP Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-deployment

I wrote an ASP.NET app in C# that consists of a WCF service and a simple website.

I have managed to deploy the project to IIS, but is there an easy way to deploy the project with only FTP access? Is there a file structure convention that is automatically picked up by the server (like a Java war) or is the process totally different? Thanks beforehand!

Cheers,
SuperTron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [MSDeploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479.aspx), which is [built into 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's Copy Web Site tool is similar in functionality to a stand-alone FTP client. In a nutshell, the Copy Web Site tool allows you to connect to a remote web site through FTP or FrontPage Server Extensions. Similar to FileZilla's user interface, the Copy Web Site user interface consists of two panes: the left pane lists the local files while the right pane lists those files on the destination server.

Note: The Copy Web Site tool is only available for Web Site Projects. Visual Studio does offer this tool when you are working with a Web Application Project.

See http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/deploying-your-site-using-visual-studio-cs for much more details.

Comment: unfortunately, my application needs to be a Web Application project.  (Well, it doesn't NEED to be, but it certainly makes everything easier!)